# Can I customize the horizontal position of scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm using a table component. The content's height is larger than the table's height. So I need a scroll bar.

But the table component is from an open-source framework, ant-design. So I can not modify the code directly.

In the following picture, I want to move the scroll bar  into the table, that is, move the scroll bar to left a little.

[image: two muppets]

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    position: relative;
    left:-10px;
}
```

I used the property `position`. 
But it didn't work. Searching google neither.

Here is an code example of codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXqqqb
So, what's the solution for moving the scroll bar a little left?

Comment: @Ari I found that  I can not override the color style either.

Comment: why don't you use the table overflow and style it like this `table::-webkit-scrollbar` ?

Comment: @A.Chao you can style the colour `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #b4d143; }`

Comment: @coops she also has to give it an `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { background-color: blue; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.list_container {
    overflow:auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="list_container">
  <div class="item_direction">1</div>
  <div class="item_direction">2</div>
  <div class="item_direction">3</div>
  <div class="item_direction">4</div>
  <div class="item_direction">5</div>
  <div class="item_direction">6</div>
  <div class="item_direction">7</div>
  <div class="item_direction">8</div>
  <div class="item_direction">9</div>
  <div class="item_direction">10</div>
  <div class="item_direction">11</div>
  <div class="item_direction">12</div>
</div>
```

So i edited my answer. this works for divs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you customize the scroll bar's horizontal position?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNZYZg  In this example, I add the position to your code. It doesn't work. @xmastertje

Comment: what exactly do you want? if you want the scrollbar in a table make a table first then i can help you further

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. It  overlooks that table's layout is far different from div. I need to focus this.

Comment: Thanks again. I almost lose my judgement after focusing this issue for too long time.